# HTML5 canvas random shapes

Tags: javascript, random, html5-canvas

Okay, so I wrote the following code in an online code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = documentById("canvasArea");
  var context = canvas.getContex("2d");

  var numCircles = 500;
  var maxRadius = 20;
  var minRadius = 3;
  var color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black", "silver", "gold", "azure", "maroon", "bisque", "pink", "navy", "lime", "cyan", "crimson", "fuschia", "teal", "olive"];
  var numColors = colors.length;

  for (var n = 0; n < numCircles; n++) {
    var xPos = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    var yPos = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    var radius = minRadius + (Math.random() * (maxRadius - minRadius));
    var colorIndex = Math.random() * (numColors - 1);
    colorIndex = Math.round(colorIndex);
    var color = colors[colorIndex];

    DrawCircle(context, xPos, yPos, radius, color);
  }
};

function drawCircle(context, xPos, yPos, radius, color) {
  var startAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 0;
  var endAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 360;
  context.shadowColor = "gray";
  context.shadowOffsetX = 1;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 1;
  context.shadowBlur = 5;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(XPos, yPos, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; height:150px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
  <canvas id="canvasArea" width="500" height="150" style="border:2px solid black">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

The following code is supposed to generate random circles, but the canvas area always turns blank. Can someone help me, please? Thank you. This is token from a book called "HTML5 for dummies.

Answer (score 0):

First issue, your body content isn't wrapped properly. Currently it's this:

```
</body>
<div style="width:500px; height:150px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
  <canvas id="canvasArea" width="500" height="150" style="border:2px solid black">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

When it should be this, with the other tags wrapped around an opening `<body>` and closing `</body>`

```
<body>
  <div style="width:500px; height:150px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
    <canvas id="canvasArea" width="500" height="150" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

The rest are naming issues:

- `var color` should be `var colors`
- `documentById` should be `document.getElementById`
- `canvas.getContex` should be `canvas.getContext`
- `DrawCircle` should be `drawCircle`. When you write a function, you have to call it with the *exact* same, case-sensitive name.
- `context.arc(XPos` should be `context.arc(xPos`. Variables are case-sensitive as well.

Lastly, you can open up your developer console with F12 (or Ctrl+Shift+I depending on the browser) and if you click the "console" tab, it'll show you a bunch of errors as hints when something goes wrong.

[image: Dev console screenshot]

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/kingdaro/pen/BYdYba?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are referencing the variable and method names wrong. You should be using an editor that validates your code. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with your code.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasArea");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var numCircles = 500;
  var maxRadius = 20;
  var minRadius = 3;
  var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black", "silver", "gold", "azure", "maroon", "bisque", "pink", "navy", "lime", "cyan", "crimson", "fuschia", "teal", "olive"];
  var numColors = colors.length;

  for (var n = 0; n < numCircles; n++) {
    var xPos = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    var yPos = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    var radius = minRadius + (Math.random() * (maxRadius - minRadius));
    var colorIndex = Math.random() * (numColors - 1);
    colorIndex = Math.round(colorIndex);
    var color = colors[colorIndex];

    drawCircle(context, xPos, yPos, radius, color);
  }
};

function drawCircle(context, xPos, yPos, radius, color) {
  var startAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 0;
  var endAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 360;
  context.shadowColor = "gray";
  context.shadowOffsetX = 1;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 1;
  context.shadowBlur = 5;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; height:150px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
  <canvas id="canvasArea" width="500" height="150" style="border:2px solid black">
    </canvas>
</div>
```